# gmaps4rails v2 migration... where is everything? (especially sidebar)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

We have a nice Rails app working using the old gmaps4rails. I've finally gotten around to trying to update to the new v2 and it seems that it is poorly documented and missing features.

**Sidebars**

Where has sidebars gone? There is no reference to it in the source or examples. Before, in my controller, I had `marker.sidebar "#{shop.name} - #{shop.location}"`. That throws an exception.

**Options**

I think this stuff is in there, but there are no examples anymore. How to recreate what this did:

```
    <%= gmaps( "map_options" => {   
                    "auto_adjust" => false, 
                    "auto_zoom" => false, 
                    "zoom" => 6, 
                    "bounds" => '[{"lat": 54, "lng": 6 }, {"lat": 48 , "lng": 15 }]'
                },
                "markers" => { 
                    "data" => @json, 
                    "options" => {"list_container" => "markers_list", "randomize" => false, "max_random_distance" => 10000 } 
                }) %>
```

I can figure out `zoom` but everything else seems vastly different.

Comment: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Why-but-why%3F

Comment: I assume that comment means that all this stuff is no longer supported.

Comment: yes, but much of it is easily doable, was simply not map concern. Tell me if you need help

Comment: The real issue is sidebar. I don't see any way of getting the markers out of gmaps4rails. I've hacked a sidebar string, but no way to tell google what I am talking about.

Comment: show your existing code, I'll help you

Comment: Here's a gist with old and new: https://gist.github.com/philsmy/7920414

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example to get your sidebar back with clean js:

```
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@shops) do |shop, marker|
    marker.lat shop.latitude
    marker.lng shop.longitude
    marker.title shop.name
    marker.json({
      id:       shop.id,
      country:  "random",
      name:     shop.name,
      location: shop.location
    })
  end

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var raw_markers   = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;
    var gmaps_markers;

    function createSidebarLi(shop_json) {
      return ("<li><a>" + shop_json.name + " - " + shop_json.location + "<\/a></li>");
    };

    function bindLiToMarker($li, marker){
      $li.click(function(){
        marker.panTo(); //to pan to the marker
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), "click"); // to open infowindow
      });
    };

    function createSidebar(){
      for (var i=0;i<raw_markers.length;i++){
        var $li = $( createSidebarLi(raw_markers[i]) );
        $li.appendTo($('#markers_list'));
        bindLiToMarker($li, gmaps_markers[i]);
      }
    };

    handler = Gmaps.build('Google', {markers: { maxRandomDistance: 10000} });
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {zoom: 6}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
      gmaps_markers = handler.addMarkers(raw_markers);
      handler.map.centerOn({ lat: 51, lng: 11 });
      createSidebar();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Sorry - got side tracked today... I'll look at it tomorrow. It looks good though, thanks very much. I believe that in v1 you had a sidebars example, so it might be nice to put the example in the v2 wiki.

Comment: Just did a quick run of it... it always uses the last marker. I have the sidebar with everything, but the click seems to be only using the last marker in the list... the $li is not an array so I guess just the last one is in place.

Comment: ok please try the updated version, always issues with loops and closures... If it works, feel free to edit the wiki

Comment: for my information, is that such a pain to migrate from v1 to v2?

Comment: Well... I have yet to do the info view. It is not so much a pain as an unknown. It is completely different and in essence basically like using a completely different gem.

Comment: I see. If it can make you a bitcomfortable, it's much faster and clearer to interact with custom js (I'm writing a full google map app, this lead to the changes)